# React useEffect update main Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image: LOGIC_SCHEMA]

I am learning the basics of react and developing my first application.
Above is the logic schema , showing 5 components.
Highlighted in red are the information I am passing between components.

Everything is working so far (using @redux) etc etc... Now I want to dynamically update the ColorCardsList when I create a card inside "ColorCardCreate" or I delete a card inside "ColorCardRow" or edit a card inside "ColorCardEdit". Based on my reading I should use useEffect hook and pass in the dependency array the props/stats. So, what I did in my ColorCardsList was creating a useEffect hook and pass [colorCards] as dependency but my application is now in an infinite loop.
Question is... is my understanding correct? is there an alternative way to update the ColorCardsList page... can you suggest some interesting reading about this topic?

Here is an example of my useEffect hook in colorCardsList. Bear in mind, as shown on the schema, I am passing the colorsCards as props from the ColorCards component. Basically inside this using effect I dispatch only some data which are not related to the colorCards..

```
    useEffect(() => {

        dispatch(getCategories())

    },[ dispatch, colorsCards ])
```